# Migration failed on upgrade Bitnami Redmine

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, centos7, redmine, bitnami

I did upgrade my Redmine (version 4.1.0) to last version (4.1.1.7) through [THIS](https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/apps/redmine/administration/upgrade/) instruction.
All was ok until i wanted to migrate database. Once i entered `sudo ruby bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production'` command the following error occured :

> Activating bundler (~> 2.1)
> Could not find 'bundler' (~> 2.1) among 5 total gem(s)
> To install the version of bundler this project requires, run gem install bundler -v '~> 2.1'

Then i try `gem install bundler -v '~> 2.1'` :

> Fetching: bundler-2.2.5.gem (100%)
> Successfully installed bundler-2.2.5
> Parsing documentation for bundler-2.2.5
> Installing ri documentation for bundler-2.2.5
> Done installing documentation for bundler after 46 seconds
> Done installing documentation for bundler after 46 seconds

and ran `sudo ruby bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` again but same error occured.

My platform is Centos 7

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My problem is solved with help of [THIS](https://www.redmine.org/boards/2/topics/61925?r=61935).

I use `bundle exec rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production` instead of `sudo ruby bin/rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=production`.

Comment: I'm glad to hear this. We will review our guide in the documentation and update it accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Bitnami Engineer here.

Please remember to load the Bitnami Environment before running any command in the installation. This way, you will ensure that you use the correct binaries when performing the operations.

You can run these commands to load the Bitnami Environment

```
cd INSTALLDIR
./use_redmine
```

https://docs.bitnami.com/installer/how-to/understand-bnconsole/

Once you do that, you can start to follow the steps in our guide to upgrade the app.

Comment: thanks,I am sure that i load the Bitnami Environment before running any command. I run only `tar czf redmine_files.tar.gz -C installdir/apps/redmine/htdocs/files` and `tar czf redmine_plugins.tar.gz -C installdir/apps/redmine/htdocs/plugins` command outside of  Bitnami Environment.